# http proxy not working with IP but hostname

Tags: networking, proxy

I'm in corporate environment and internet is running behind firewall & proxy.

Due to recently had change in internet proxy server, browser proxy is not working with IP but hostname. It ask for username/password again and again (407) but got not success if I use IP.

**Proxy has only one IP fixed.**

I have tried it in both InternetExplorer/Firefox but not working with IP.

Now I have a java program that was working fine with proxy, user/password before recent change but now it has same issue as mention above. And it is neither works with hostname nor IP as It tries to connect with IP only & got message read time out with 407.

Why am I asking here is I believe even browser gets IP from host name and then tries to connect to proxy.

My question is what is work around to work with IP as I need this in java program.

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that you company is using a SSO login for the proxy. In such a case you must maje the URL coincide with the Kerberos realm, which is not expected at all to be the IP address.